# Parsing google geocode result in java - getting JSONArray[0] not found (It is there)

Tags: java, json, google-maps, geocoding

EDIT: I have another program, which uses direction service. It works. When I use that code in this geocode project, it throws the same error. (Eclipse, Java EE, Tomcat7)

for reference here's the request

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=vancouver,bc&sensor=true

Here's there code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject res = obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
```

String "s" is the return json. This works:

```
 System.out.println(obj.getJSONArray("results");
```

Though as soon as I try getJSONObject(0) I get the error. I was working with the directions service prior to this and it sends a very similar result.. which was working for me. Any advice is much appreciated! This has eaten a couple hours of my night now so I thought I'd seek some help.

Comment: Your code is working. `getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)` is giving the result.

Comment: @Jhanvi Hmm. Any reason I'd be getting this particular error then? I just tried my old code for the directions service and it's giving me the same error now as well.

Comment: Can you write the json that you are parsing?? Is it the same link as mentioned in the question??

Comment: The JSON return is identical. I'm using the same link as well. It's gotta be something wrong with the json package I'm thinking..

Comment: Is this your import - `import org.json.JSONObject;` ??

Answer (score 2):

```
String lat = obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (Especially if it looks awfully similar to the original code.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               **"lat"** : 37.4223329,
               **"lng"** : -122.0844192
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4236818802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0830702197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4209839197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0857681802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

`lat(Latitude)` and `lng(Longitude)` are of type `Double`, hence the correct code (if you need latitude and longitude as `String`s) is:

```
String latitude = Double.toString(jsonTree.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat"));

String longitude = Double.toString(jsonTree.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng"));
```